# Track emails sent with DMARC enabled

Tags: spf, mx-record, dmarc

Is it possible to track which emails are / have been sent on behalf of my domain by an authorized external server via SPF?

I have DMARC enabled and would like to monitor what external domains are sending, since I don't have direct access to them.

Comment: You can *ask* receivers to send you delivery reports via your DMARC config, but you can't guarantee that they will do so, bearing in mind that if everyone did that it would represent a doubling of email traffic. I recommend using an external DMARC tracking system like postmark or dmarcian.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you might want to have a look at SPF macros: https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#spf-macros

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can but the problem is that DMARC reports are notoriously hard to read without some sort of tools such as dmarcian, Agari, or some other service that provides a user-friendly interface to read the data.

If your visible from is example.com and em.foo.com (an external domain)is the SMTP FROM domain then that's what I think you're looking for. DMARC reports for sure provide this data. The trick is getting these daily XML reports sent to a service that can present these reports in a readable way.

If you don't want to pay for a service such as DMARCIAN there are free and open-source DMARC software you can find on GitHub and elsewhere.